# Help rerouting to new "virtual" subfolder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having problems rerouting my pages from website.com/controller/action to website.com/admin/controller/action.

I tried adding this to global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin",
    "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = "UrlParameter.Optional" }
);
```

It worked but it also rewrote my other links adding the word "admin" in unintended places.

My problem is similar to this: [ASP.NET MVC Routing, Need help creating route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525261/asp-net-mvc-routing-need-help-creating-route)

Comment: Solved this using MVC areas. But the problem with areas is that you can not simply cut/paste your views and controllers to the new area - you have to recreate all of the controllers to make them work again. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using MVC areas. But the problem with areas is that you can not simply cut/paste your views and controllers to the new area - you have to recreate all of the controllers to make them work again. Hope this helps someone.